# How to add space on a complex string?

Tags: python, string

I have this string that act's like a progress bar

```
etichetta_download_mp3["text"] = '\r' + 'Download : %s%s%.2f%% ' % ('█' * int(size * 20 / contentsize), '' * (20 - int(size * 20 / contentsize)), float(size / contentsize * 100))
```

And looks like this :
[image]

Please could you explain me how to add a single space like `" "` in the red arrow? Like end of the bar, space and then the 100 % percentage, because in my image they are too closed, probably it's an easy task but i can't understand how to do it ... thanks!

Comment: `.....2f% % '` ?

Comment: Hi @MauriceMeyer, i tried to add the space between the 2 %, typing : %s%s%.2f% % ,but the program gives me an error, TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: This pattern should work: `'Download : %s%s%.2f %% '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One format that should work is probably `'Download : %s%s %.2f%%'`. The space should be before `%.2f` since that's where your percentage value is being formatted.

Example here:

```
# some dummy values
size = 1
contentsize = 5

fmt = 'Download : %s%s %.2f%%' % ('█' * int(size * 20 / contentsize), '' * (20 - int(size * 20 / contentsize)), float(size / contentsize * 100))

print(fmt)
```

Output:

```
Download : ████ 20.00%
```

Edit: also, I realized your second `%s` is unnecessary because you're trying to insert `'' * (20 - int(size * 20 / contentsize))`, but `''` is zero-length, so it doesn't actually add anything. This would do the equivalent of what you're trying to achieve (notice one fewer `%s`, and removing the second calculation you have).

```
# some dummy values
size = 1
contentsize = 5

fmt = 'Download : %s %.2f%%' % ('█' * int(size * 20 / contentsize), float(size / contentsize * 100))

print(fmt)
```

Comment: Thanks it works i upvoted and approved your answer! How do you figured it out where to put the space? I'm still a beginner expecially with these complex strings

Comment: An easy way is to break it down by how many substitutions you have in your string. `%s`, `%s`, `%0.2f` are the three you have, so the thing you were trying to put a space between was all the blocks and your number, which are between the 2nd and 3rd substitutions. Also, looking more closely, I realize your second substitution is unnecessary because `''` is a zero-length space. Check my edit to see what I mean.